# Remove table header and body cells using eq

Tags: jquery, dynamic, indexing, html-table

I'm working on a project that the table must be dynamically adding columns and delete it if the user feels that the column is not used.

My problem is when I'm deleting the column header, only one td in tbody is deleted. Here is my code that I used:

```
$("#tbl thead th:eq("+index+")").remove();
$("#tbl tbody > td:eq("+index+")").remove();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
$("#tbl thead th:eq("+index+")").remove();
$("#tbl tbody tr").find("td:eq("+index+")").remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xWnW3/)

or

```
$("#tbl tr td,th").filter(':nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').remove();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GXQeN/)